# How to display data that are being call in ajax in ASP.net mvc

Tags: arrays, asp.net, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

[image]

Hello Guys I'm having hard time in displaying data that are being call in ajax into the view.
I'm new with ajax.
When I'm searching Id I want to auto fill other fields.

thank you for replying

Comment: Could you share your code of model ? What's  the relation about  searching Id and other fields that you want to auto fill ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.

AutoFilledModel:

```
public class AutoFilledModel
    {
        [Key]
        public string ProjectId { get; set; } 
        public string Region { get; set; }            
    }
```

AutoFilledController:

```
public class AutoFilledController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> projectidlist = new()
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "178290", Text = "178290" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "192834", Text = "192834" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "194364", Text = "194364" }    
            };//you can use your way to pass dropdownlist

            //assigning SelectListItem to view Bag
            ViewBag.projectidlist = projectidlist;
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult GetDropDownList(string id)
        {
            var autoFilledModels= new List<AutoFilledModel>()
         {
            new AutoFilledModel()  {ProjectId="178290",Region="Nordic"},
            new AutoFilledModel()  {ProjectId="192834",Region="Luzon"},
            new AutoFilledModel()  {ProjectId="194364",Region="Luzon45"}
         };
           // you can get data from database too
            var result = autoFilledModels.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ProjectId == id);
            return Json(result);
        }
    }
```

Index view:

```
@model AutoFilledModel

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProjectId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ProjectId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.projectidlist"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Region" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Region" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Region" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/jscript">
              $(function() {
                $("#ProjectId").change(function() {
                  var selectedid = $('option:selected').val();
                    if (selectedid > 0) { 
                    $.ajax({
                      url: "/AutoFilled/GetDropDownList",
                      data: {
                        id: selectedid          
                      },
                      type: "Post",
                      dataType: "Json",
                      success: function(result) {                         
                          document.getElementById('Region').value = result.region;                        
                      },
                      error: function() {           
                      }
                    });
                  }
                });
              });
            </script>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much and im sorry my mistake its in asp.net mvc.. not in asp.net core

Comment: @RhodneyNoquiao What's the version of asp.net you used?

Comment: MVC 5.. i really appreciate ur effort..and it is the same logic with searchable and drop down?

Comment: @RhodneyNoquiao yes, you can have a try. And  use your own drop down.